# Clear table Row on dropdown change jQuery

Tags: jquery

I wanted to delete the entire table row on dropdown change. I tried  `.empty()`
but it also deletes the table. `.remove` only delete one table row.

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rdanalasa/pyqhh45p/)

```
function reset_table() {
  alert("table has been reset!");
}
$("#service_type").change(reset_table);
```

Comment: when on change, do a loop to read all the row and perform the same action that you had mention

Comment: Looking at your fiddle, in the `delete_row()` function you have a `$(this)`, but in that context, `$(this)` won't return anything.

Comment: @MingleLi sorry its working alright.You just need to insert value on it first.When delete is triggered it will remove the inserted value.

Comment: If you want to remove the entire table row upon click of `Delete` use `$(this).parent().parent().remove();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you trying to achieve? you trying to reset, not delete, right?
https://jsfiddle.net/pyqhh45p/64/

```
 function reset_table()
 {
    $('table').find('input[type="text"], select').val('');
 }
```

Comment: Yes,This is better than deleting the entire row.